# Run a java application in Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

I am trying to run a RSPS ( Runescape Private Server ) on my Ubuntu VPS.

I can run it in windows fine with an IDE but having problems running it via Ubuntu.

This is what i'm trying to run

```
java -classpath bin:deps/* org.perception.Server
```

I get this error

```
    Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/rspserver/mvh/AuthService
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rspserver.mvh.AuthService
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Comment: if your bin folder contains jar files, this won't work, cuz Java won't load jars in folder, jars should explicitly declared to Java for it load them, ex : bin/lib1.jar:bin/lib2.jar ...

Comment: more informations here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: check in your IDE if there's any option to deploy your code in a JAR file with all the necessary dependencies

Comment: Add the directory containing the jars to your PATH and re-run

Comment: You need to list individual jar files on the classpath, like this: `java -classpath bin"$(find deps/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.jar' -printf ':%p')" org.perception.Server`